# How to split digits and text

Tags: python, replace

I have a dataset like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'a' : [5, 5, '2 bad']})
```

I want to convert this to

```
{ 'a.digits' : [5, 5, 2], 'a.text' : [nan, nan, 'bad']}
```

I can get 'a.digits' as bellow

```
data['a.digits'] = data['a'].replace('[^0-9]', '', regex = True) 
5    2
2    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

When i do

```
data['a'] = data['a'].replace('[^\D]', '', regex = True)
```

or

```
data['a'] = data['a'].replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex = True)
```

i get

```
5      2
bad    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

What's wrong? How to remove digits?

Comment: The replace() method works only on strings, but it does nothing on integers. That is why your solution does not work.

Comment: You could use a loop to check the type of each element, and skip it if it is an integer (or keep only strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would suffice?

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: import re

In [10]: data['a.digits'] = data['a'].apply(lambda x: int(re.sub(r'[\D]', '', str(x))))

In [12]: data['a.text'] = data['a'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[\d]', '', str(x)))

In [13]: data.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
Out[13]: 
       a a.digits a.text
0      5        5    NaN
1      5        5    NaN
2  2 bad        2    bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a space between 2 and the word bad, you can do this:

`data['Text'] = data['a'].str.split(' ').str[1]`